# How to give the file path for $http

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```
'use strict';

foodMeApp.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.url = '/server/api.php'; // The url of our search, some thing wrong here
             
        // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
        $scope.search = function() {
             
            // Create the http post request
            // the data holds the keywords
            // The request is a JSON request.
            $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).
            success(function(data, status) {
               ...
            }).error(function(data, status) {
               ...   
            });
        };
});
```

what is wrong here $scope.url = '/server/api.php';

Have attached directory structure and the error,

[image]

browser error: 
[image]

Please let me know, if needed more info

Comment: I think, your server folder is undefined, see some notification symbol in that folder

Comment: Try $scope.url = 'server/api.php';

Answer (score 0):

I think move your `server` folder to the `app` directory will solve this issue ;)

Comment: no friend, still the same "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://foodme/server/api.php". :(

Comment: What if you try to access to `foodme/server/api.php` manually ?

Comment: Move `server` to your `app` folder ;)

Comment: 'Move server to your app folder', this worked, Thanks, But can you tell me why out as show in diagram.

Comment: You can solve this issue by validating my answer ;)
I've "suggested" this because you've got and an `index.html` at the root of `app`.. and it could be the only logical solution

Answer (score 0):

> I think, your server folder is undefined, see some notification symbol in that folder

or

try

```
$scope.url = 'server/api.php';
```

or, try

```
$scope.url = '../server/api.php';
```

Comment: $scope.url = '../server/api.php'; looks correct, but still not working. but when i did 'Move server to your app folder ;)'By Paul Rad i comments, it worked. But why not your solution.